# How to test social login application written using nodejs and passport with the help of mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, passport.js

I have written a nodejs application which allows login using google account. There is no other login method.

I am writing test scripts for mocha. There are some apis require authentication to work. So how can i first authenticate user using google account and test apis.

Answer (score 1):

you can try PhantomJS workflow for signing in in Google first and than following link for passport.js signin route, but be aware that after about 10 attempt to sign in using Phantomjs they can block your account.